# Replace meta tags by node.js. React build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

How I can replace metaTags by node.js. I wont use ejs, this code working if I comment (express.static), but then I have blanc page. Can I rewrite html by node server?

```
const indexPath  = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html');

static resources should just be served as they are
app.use(express.static(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
));


app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    fs.readFile(indexPath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error during file reading', err);
            return res.status(404).end()
        }

        // inject meta tags
        htmlData = htmlData.replace(
            "<title>express</title>",
            `<title>1234</title>`
        )
            .replace('__META_OG_TITLE__', '1')
            .replace('__META_OG_DESCRIPTION__', '2')
        return res.send(htmlData);
    });
});
```